# IOS, из JavaScript в Objective C

Tags: ios

У меня на View лежит 2 компоненты: WebView и TextField. В WebView находится поле(едит), как мне реализовать следующее: я ввожу в это поле значение, а оно автоматически записывается в компонент TextField.
Кончно понятно, что практического значения эта процедура значения не имет, но хотелось бы понять механизм, как из WebView можно передавать какиенибуть события в нативное приложение. Знаю что такое возможно, например, http://phonegap.com/ - библиотека умеет делать это, но к сожелению моего скила не хватит чтобы в этом проекте найти то что мне необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно повесить событие на input (ваше
поле(едит)), находящийся в webView, с помощью stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.

Это событие должно редиректить webView на фейковый урл, в который будет записываться текущее значение input'a, например так: "appname:fillTextField:текущее значение поля"

В методе делегата webView webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: проверяем урл, и если он удовлетворяет нашим условиям (начинается с appname) вызываем метод заполнения textEdit и возвращаем NO, в противном случае возвращаем YES.

Вот пример:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *html = @"<html><body><input type=\"text\" id=\"targetField\"></body></html>";

    [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSString *js = @"var textField = document.getElementById('targetField'); textField.onkeyup = function(){ document.location = 'appname:fillTextField:' + this.value } ";

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSString *urlString = [[request URL] absoluteString];
    NSArray *components = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    if ([[components objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"appname"])
    {
        id parameter = [components objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *methodName = [components objectAtIndex:1];
        if ([methodName isEqualToString:@"fillTextField"])
        {
            [self fillTextField:parameter];
        }
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)fillTextField:(NSString *)newValue
{
    [_textField setText:newValue];
}
```